# iOS 6 auto rotate confusion

Tags: iphone, rotation, ios6, autorotate

I have my entire interface in one Storyboard. How can I make most of the ViewControllers only support a portrait orientation while only a couple supporting all orientations. I can't understand apples new auto rotate system. Also, how can I make this backwards compatable to iOS 5?

Comment: Here's something I wrote about my experience with the migration - http://blog.logichigh.com/2012/11/13/support-ios-4-devices-while-building-with-the-ios-6-sdk/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Navigation Controller subclass, forward the decision to the top view controller in the stack:

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

Creating a separate storyboard file for this is the worst path to follow, it'll be a maintenance nightmare to keep them in sync with your app updates.

Comment: That makes the most sense and I will be implementing that. I don't know how else to use auto-layout and maintain iOS 5 compatability

Answer (score 1):

You should watch the [WWDC'2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) especially the ones in the "Essentials" section talking about rotations.

The one called "T Evolution of View Controllers in iOS" explains the subject about rotations (and how to make them compatible with various iOS version) in great details, with explanations and code samples, and I couldn't explain it better than Apple ;)

Comment: I watched the video 2 times. From my interpretations of it i conclude that i have to subclass a navController to achieve what i want. I tried that and it worked...for the first viewController in the stack. I don't know how to make it work for vc's further down the stack. BASICALLY all of my vc's either will, or will not rotate.

Comment: Then why don't you implement/override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in each of your ViewController, depending on if it has to rotate or not?!

Comment: I did, and I checked using NSLog and it gets called. But whatever behavior I set in the first ViewController (AutoRotate=YES, supportIngerfaceOrientation=Portrait) is what happens in all other view controllers that get pushed on the navigation stack. Also I checked on the other vc's with NSLog to see if they check for shouldAutorotate and that never gets called

Comment: In your root subclass, you should call down to the topViewController's method, instead of returning actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Well i kinda hacked my way around this one. 
here is my Subclassed NavController.h

```
#import "RootVC.h"

@implementation RootVC

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([def integerForKey:@"Should Rotate"] == 1) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
@end
```

I just set an integer for @"Should Rotate" in defaults on each View Controller in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a native rootViewController, you have to extend it to support iOS5 gracefully. This is said in the above mentioned WWDC video.

Basically, if you are using a UINavigationViewController, extend it and override its `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` method. In there, look into your children (you can just query the older methods for interface orientation you have) and determine what should be supported and return the correct value.

The reason you need to do this to be backward compatible is 2 things:
- they've deprecated the old way of rotating stuff
- only rootViewController ever gets the rotation call. The parent should decide for its children what orientation it needs to be in. All these changes are inline with the new AutoLayout stuff.

After you extend your nav controller, go to your storyboard -> select the root controller (navigation controller in this case) -> set the class to your newly written class.

HTH

Comment: Ok, i improvised early in this project to maintain iOS 5 compatibility, but still be able to use the AWESOME new Auto Layout system. My initial Storyboard is just 1 View Controller embedded in a navController. In the implementation of that viewController i check the current OS version, then present a storyboard. I have 2 identical ones, except one has auto-layout enabled. ALL O HAD TO DO was set that initial navController's class to my "RootVC" that has the 6 lines or so of the new auto-rotate API. I do have to say, this approach is far more confusing and I think poorly explained by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack I used to support both iOS 5 devices and iOS 6 devices (as well as iPhone 5).  In your prefix file, add the following #define

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0 // Only do the rotation fix if we are building with iOS 6 API
@protocol DeprecatedRotationSupported
@optional
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toOrientation;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
@end

#define shouldAutorotateToInterface_fixed shouldAutorotate \
{ \
    UIViewController <DeprecatedRotationSupported> *selfTyped = (UIViewController <DeprecatedRotationSupported> *) self; \
\
    if(![self respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:)]) \
        return NO; \
    int optionCount = 0; \
    for(UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; orientation <= UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft; orientation++) \
    { \
        if(![selfTyped shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:orientation]) continue; \
        if(optionCount==1) return YES; \
        optionCount++; \
    } \
    return NO; \
} \
\
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations \
{ \
    UIViewController <DeprecatedRotationSupported> *selfTyped = (UIViewController <DeprecatedRotationSupported> *) self; \
\
    if(![self respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:)]) return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; \
    \
    NSUInteger supported = 0; \
    \
    if([selfTyped shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]) supported |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; \
    if([selfTyped shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]) supported |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft; \
    if([selfTyped shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]) supported |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight; \
    if([selfTyped shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown]) supported |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown; \
    return supported;  \
} \
\
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
#else // We are building with the older API, leave shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation alone.
#define shouldAutorotateToInterface_fixed shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
#endif // __IPHONE_6_0
```

Then, anywhere you use shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: instead use shouldAutorotateToInterface_fixed:

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Subclassed RootNavController.h

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.topViewController.view.superview)
    {
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```