# How can i fix landscape for iPad in universal app in iOS application?

Tags: ios5

By  using Xcode4.5 i developed universal app, i want to make iPad version only in Landscape mode.

Here i have tired

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) 
    {
        return YES;
    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) 
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;    
}
```

Even though i have tried like the above code , it did appear in  Portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

are you testing this in ios5 or ios6?  In ios6 the shouldAutoRotate method  is ignored.  You need to use

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

}
```

and

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutoRotate {
}
```

You can find more info on that here: [iOS 6 auto rotate confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546498/ios-6-auto-rotate-confusion)