# Device orientation handling in iOS 6 during view load?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I have a Tab bar application. I was using XCode 4.3.3. I have upgraded to 4.5.2 with iOS6 stuffs.

My code in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` for each view will check the current device orientation and place all the UI components properly.

But after upgrading to iOS 6, this code is not executing. I have tried for almost one day to fix this, but had no luck.

I have also tried

```
UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

in `viewLoad`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`

What should I do if I want to check the orientation during the view load and place the UI components to appropriate places during view load. Kindly give your suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526054/autorotate-in-ios-6-has-strange-behaviour

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546498/ios-6-auto-rotate-confusion

Comment: Check this link : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/check-device-orientation.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you want to check which is current orientation, then you just write in prifix.pch below line

```
 #define isPortrait [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
```

then where you want to check orientation ,write condition like below

```
    if(isPortrait)
    {
       //portrait mode....
    }
    else
    {
       //landscape mode....
    }
```

let me know it is working or not...

Happy coding!

Comment: You are right, this is the only solutions. Thought of giving my answer. You did.. Its good. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: but it wont work in runtime device orientation.... when view is navigate another view at that time only it will works otherwise these methods it wont calling....

Answer (score 2):

To check orientation in ios6,you will have to write below methods and also in your info.plist you will have to define which orientation you want...

let me know whether it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
     return NO;
   }

   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;//you can write here which ever orientation you want..
   }
```

Comment: I have added this code, but this didn't solved my problem. supportedInterfaceOrientations method is called when my viewController loaded, but there i am unable to find the orientation using UIDeviceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

Comment: have you added your orientation in info.plist file???it is very important to add the orientations which you want to support in device

Comment: That is also done, but my problem is to find the interface orientation during the view load. Previously i was doing my required stuffs in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. Now there is no such delegate method.. :(

Answer (score 2):

you manage Oriantation like this ways:-

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

and check every time in `ViewWillApear` device Oriantation like:-

```
- (void)willRotateToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newOrientation {
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
        {
            if (newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

              //set your landscap View Frame
                [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

            }



        }
        else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
        {
            if(newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
      //set your Potrait View Frame
                [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

            }
        }
        // Handle rotation
    }


    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [self willRotateToOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];  
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    }
```

**UPDATE**

likely people use checking device`orientation` like below way in putting this line in to `ViewWillApear`:-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceRotated:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
-(void)deviceRotated:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //Do your stuff for landscap
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
      //Do your stuff for potrait

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At viewDidLoad method you need to check for the same and accordingly you need to write code unless it may affect view if it not in on portrait.