# orientation is not getting fix ipad 6?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hi I have developed an application in ios 4, now I am building it on ios 6 but the orientation is not working. I am using splitview for iPad.

Comment: have you read the documentation of how the autorotation is being supported in iOS6...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue before.

I fixed it by setting the rootview controller of window as UISplitView.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
}
```

Where `UISplitViewController *viewController;`

Answer (score 0):

check my answers on this link my friend.

[Device orientation handling in iOS 6 during view load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189828/device-orientation-handling-in-ios-6-during-view-load/14195659#14195659)

if you are not getting then do tell me..

Let me know it is working or not...

Happy Coding!!!